# How to generate new column based on multiple values from another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I create a new column in a Pandas DataFrame that compresses/collapses multiple values at once from another column? Also, is it possible to use a default value so that you don't have to explicitly write out **all** the value mappings?

I'm referring to a process that is often called "variable recoding" in statistical software such as [SPSS](https://wlm.userweb.mwn.de/SPSS/wlmsreco.htm) and [Stata](https://www.stata.com/manuals/drecode.pdf).

### Example

Suppose I have a DataFrame with 1,000 observations. The only column in the DataFrame is called `col1` and it has 26 unique values (the letters `A` through `Z`). Here's a reproducible example of my starting point:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string

np.random.seed(666)
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_uppercase),size=1000)})
```

I want to create a new column called `col2` according to the following mapping:

- If `col1` is equal to either `A`, `B` or `C`, `col2` should receive `AA`
- If `col1` is equal to either `D`, `E` or `F`, `col2` should receive `MM`
- For all other values in `col1`, `col2` should receive `ZZ`

I know I can partially do this using Pandas' `replace` function, but it has two problems. The first is that the `replace` function doesn't allow you to condense multiple input values into one single response value. This forces me to write out `df['col1'].replace({'A':'AA','B':'AA','C':'AA'})` instead of something simpler like `df['col1'].replace({['A','B','C']:'AA'})`.

The second problem is that the `replace` function doesn't have an `all_other_values` keyword or anything like that. This forces me to manually write out the ENTIRE value mappings like this `df['col1'].replace({'A':'AA','B':'AA',...,'G':'ZZ','H':'ZZ','I':'ZZ',...,'X':'ZZ','Y':'ZZ','Z':'ZZ'})` instead of something simpler like `df['col1'].replace(dict_for_abcdef, all_other_values='ZZ')`

Is there another way to use the `replace` function that I'm missing that would allow me to do what I'm asking? Or is there another Pandas function that enables you to so similar things to what I describe above?

### Dirty implementation

Here is a "dirty" implementation of what I'm looking for using `loc`:

```py
df['col2'] = 'ZZ' # Initiate the column with the default "all_others" value
df.loc[df['col1'].isin(['A','B','C']),'col2'] = 'AA'  # Mapping from "A","B","C" to "AA"
df.loc[df['col1'].isin(['D','E','F']),'col2'] = 'MM'  # Mapping from "D","E","F" to "MM"
```

I find this solution a bit messy and was hoping something a bit cleaner existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can try with [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) which takes a list of conditions, a list of values, and also a default:

```
conds = [df['col1'].isin(['A', 'B', 'C']),
         df['col1'].isin(['D', 'E', 'F'])]
values = ['AA', 'MM']
df['col2'] = np.select(conds, values, default='ZZ')
```

Can also use [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) instead of [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
conds = [df['col1'].between('A', 'C'),
         df['col1'].between('D', 'F')]
values = ['AA', 'MM']
df['col2'] = np.select(conds, values, default='ZZ')
```

---

Sample Input and Output:

```
import string

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

letters = string.ascii_uppercase
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': list(letters)[:10]})
```

`df`:

```
  col1 col2
0    A   AA
1    B   AA
2    C   AA
3    D   MM
4    E   MM
5    F   MM
6    G   ZZ
7    H   ZZ
8    I   ZZ
9    J   ZZ
```

Answer (score 1):

np.select(condition, choice, alternative). For conditions, check numerals between a defined range

```
c=[df['col1'].between('A','C'),df['col1'].between('E','F')]
CH=['AA','MM']
df=df.assign(col2=np.select(c,CH,'ZZ'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This looks concise, but I'd like to avoid the `between` operator. The letter values in this case were just an simplified example. In most real cases these will likely be complicated strings that represent unique categories, so the `between` keyword might not work very well.

Comment: Noted, appreciate not always possible to frame question on forum as to real life case. Happy to help further if it gets more complicated